# arrays A and B of integer numbers of length N, find the maximum value on an optimal path from A[0] to B[-1]

Tags: python, arrays, list, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a problem where I have two 1D arrays, A and B, each of length N. I need to find the maximum value of an optimal path from A[0] to B[-1], moving only right or down in a 2xN grid. Here's the code I've written using dynamic programming:

```py
def max_path_sum(A, B): 
    N = len(A) 
    dp = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(2)] 
    dp[0][0] = A[0] 
    for i in range(1, N): 
        dp[0][i] = dp[0][i - 1] + A[i] 
        dp[1][0] = dp[0][0] + B[0] 
    for i in range(1, N): 
        dp[1][i] = max(dp[1][i - 1] + B[i], dp[0][i] + B[i]) 
    return dp[1][N - 1]
```

This function calculates the maximum path sum in a 2xN grid. I used a dynamic programming approach where dp is a 2xN grid storing the maximum sum at each position.

My Question: Is there a more efficient way to write this function, or can the current implementation be optimized further for better performance?

Comment: I added the python tag, because in other languages, B[-1] is an invalid array access.

Comment: By improving performance, do you mean specifically improving asymptotic time complexity (big O), or are you also looking for other optimizations that make the same algorithm faster? E.g. using a numpy array instead of a python list.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithmically, what you've come up with seems good.  But there are a couple of little things that can be cleaned up.

First, you've computed `dp[1][0] = dp[0][0] + B[0]` repeatedly inside the loop. That could be calculated once right after `dp[0][0] = A[0]` since it doesn't depend on any other values of `dp`.

Also, you don't need two separate loops since the values of `dp[1][i]` don't depend on `dp[0][j]` for any value of `j` greater than `i`.  The computation of `dp[1][i]` can be done in the same loop as the computation of `dp[0][i]`.

But these changes don't improve the algorithm, just your implementation.

```py
def max_path_sum(A, B): 
    N = len(A) 
    dp = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(2)] 
    dp[0][0] = A[0] 
    dp[1][0] = dp[0][0] + B[0]
    for i in range(1, N): 
        dp[0][i] = dp[0][i - 1] + A[i] 
        dp[1][i] = max(dp[1][i - 1] + B[i], dp[0][i] + B[i]) 
    return dp[1][N - 1]
```